# Not able to get result set when ASSOCIATORS are used in WMI query using perl script

Tags: windows, perl, hyper-v

I am not able to get result set when ASSOCIATORS are used in WMI query using perl script. Can someone please help on this?

```
 $str = "ASSOCIATORS OF {($cs->Path_)->Path} WHERE resultClass = Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent";
 $components = $wmi->ExecQuery($str); #Here I am not able to find $components
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved the above error by changing the code as:

```
$str = "ASSOCIATORS OF {$cs->{Path_}->{Path}} WHERE resultClass = Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent";
$components = $wmi->ExecQuery($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to query for KVP data in Server 2012 or 2012 R2 has changed versus how it was in Server 2008, so trying to use the root/virtualization WMI namespace will not work.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/taylorb/archive/2012/12/05/customizing-the-key-value-pair-kvp-integration-component.aspx

That link shows how the WMI has changed, and how you can query to get the right data.